# Getting Started - Collection is not populating View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I try to render this data by doing

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
console.log(this.collection);
```

I'm assuming a reset event is called when I do a fetch but I'm not 100% sure.

My Collection is defined as such:

```
var FavoritesTable = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    Name: 'FavoritesTable',
    model: FavoritesRow,
    url: $A.Reg.get('_path_ajax'),
    initialize: function (models, options) {
        console.log(this.fetch(options));
    }
});
```

Comment: so if you do function() { console.log('gonna render'); this.render(); } that gets called right? If it does then I guess you are not passing the collection to your template. Also if you are waiting for a fetch the correct event to listen to is sync as Daniel said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source, it does not trigger a `reset` but a `sync` event.

Answer (score 3):

If you want `fetch` to reset a collection you can pass `{reset: true}` as options. [Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch).